# Change the Datatype of columns in PySpark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an input dataframe(**ip_df**), data in this dataframe looks like as below:

```
id            col_value
1               10
2               11
3               12
```

Data type of id and col_value is **String**

I need to get another dataframe(**output_df**), having datatype of id as string and col_value column as decimal**(15,4)**. THere is no data transformation, just data type conversion.
Can i use it using PySpark. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 12):

Try using the [**cast**](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.cast) method:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType
<your code>
output_df = ip_df.withColumn("col_value",ip_df["col_value"].cast(DecimalType()))
```

Comment: It is giving error-name 'DecimalType' is not defined

Comment: You need to import it

Comment: from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType

Answer (score 5):

try below statement.

```
output_df = ip_df.withColumn("col_value",ip_df["col_value"].cast('float'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change multiple column types

- Using `withColumn()` -

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType, StringType

output_df = ip_df \
  .withColumn("col_value", ip_df["col_value"].cast(DecimalType())) \
  .withColumn("id", ip_df["id"].cast(StringType()))
```

- Using `select()`

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType, StringType

output_df = ip_df.select(
  (ip_df.id.cast(StringType())).alias('id'),
  (ip_df.col_value.cast(DecimalType())).alias('col_value')
)
```

- Using `spark.sql()`

```py
ip_df.createOrReplaceTempView("ip_df_view")

output_df = spark.sql('''
SELECT 
    STRING(id),
    DECIMAL(col_value)
FROM ip_df_view;
''')
```