# Efficient way to transform several columns to string in PySpark

Tags: python, types, casting, pyspark

It is well documented on SO ([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284620/how-to-change-a-dataframe-column-from-string-type-to-double-type-in-pyspark), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453294/change-the-datatype-of-columns-in-pyspark-dataframe), [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46956026/how-to-convert-column-with-string-type-to-int-form-in-pyspark-data-frame), ...) how to transform a single variable to `string` type in `PySpark` by analogy:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType    
spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('name_of_column', spark_df[name_of_column].cast(StringType()))
```

However, when you have several columns that you want transform to `string` type, there are several methods to achieve it:

***Using `for` loops -- Successful approach in my code:***

Trivial example:

```
to_str = ['age', 'weight', 'name', 'id']
for col in to_str:
  spark_df = spark_df.withColumn(col, spark_df[col].cast(StringType()))
```

which is a valid method but I believe not the optimal one that I am looking for.

***Using list comprehensions -- Not succesful in my code:***

My wrong example:

```
spark_df = spark_df.select(*(col(c).cast("string").alias(c) for c in to_str))
```

Not succesful as I receive the error message:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

My question then would be: **which would be the optimal way to transform several columns to string in PySpark based on a list of column names like `to_str` in my example?**

Thanks in advance for your advice.

> POSTERIOR CLARIFICATION EDIT:

Thanks to @Rumoku and @pault feedback:

Both code lines are correct:

```
spark_df = spark_df.select(*(col(c).cast("string").alias(c) for c in to_str)) # My initial list comprehension expression is correct.
```

and

```
spark_df = spark_df.select([col(c).cast(StringType()).alias(c) for c in to_str]) # Initial answer proposed by @Rumoku is correct.
```

I was receiving the error messages from `PySpark` given that I previously changed the name of the object `to_str` for `col`. As @pault explains: `col` (the list with the desired string variables) had the same name as the function `col` of the list comprehension, that´s why `PySpark` complained. Simply renaming `col` to `to_str`, and updating `spark-notebook` fixed everything.

Comment: Spark is lazy, so, your for loop will build single query and executes later on. There should not be a big difference between for loop and list comprehensions in term of performance.

Comment: Hi @Rumoku, thanks for your answer. Do you know which one would be the correct syntax of the list comprehension option in PySpark that didn´t work in my case? The line I used was: spark_df = spark_df.select(*(col(c).cast("string").alias(c) for c in to_str)), with error message: "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: Somewhere you have overwritten a variable as a string- my guess is perhaps `col` -> can you do `print(type(col))`?

Comment: @NuValue that is exactly it. In your `for` loop version you assigned `col` to a string (`for col in to_str:`). Then you are trying to use it later on as a function (`col(c).cast()`).

Comment: @pault, you are totally right. I needed to update my Spark-Notebook, because I removed the name of that object 'col' afterwards. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
spark_df = spark_df.select([col(c).cast(StringType()).alias(c) for c in to_str])
```

Comment: Hi @Rumoku, thanks for your answer. After executing your line of code I get the following message: "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable". I wonder if maybe the function StringType() is the one that is causing problem in that line? I imported the module naturally with: "from pyspark.sql.types import StringType", previously.

Comment: do `print(spark_df)` on a previous line. I wonder if it's dataframe at all.

Comment: thanks, print(spark_df) prints the following output: DataFrame[ID: bigint, Source: string, NickName: string, EqType: bigint]

Comment: how did you import `col`?

Comment: Now it works perfectly @Rumoku, it was the refreshing of the Spark-Notebook what was needed. Will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is `col()` for the list comprehension part in your solution, but anyone looking for the solution can try this -

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType 

to_str = ['age', 'weight', 'name', 'id']

spark_df = spark_df.select(
  [spark_df[c].cast(StringType()).alias(c) for c in to_str]
)
```

To replace all the columns to `str` type, replace `to_str` with `spark_df.columns`.